# What does the leading "-" (dash) mean in output of `p4 where`?

Tags: perforce

I have a single directory of depot (`//depot/branch`) mapped to three places in a workspace(`//user_space`). Output of `p4 where` looks like this

```
$ p4 where //depot/branch/README.md    
-//depot/branch/README.md //user_space/branch/README.md C:\dev\branch\README.md
-//depot/branch/README.md //user_space/branch2/README.md C:\dev\branch2\README.md
//depot/branch/README.md //user_space/branch3/README.md C:\dev\branch3\README.md
```

What's the meaning of the leading dashed in the command output?

The [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_where.html) doesn't seem to explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a minus sign (as in `3 - 2 = 1`); it indicates an exclusion.

What the output is saying is:

- this file *isn't* mapped to `branch1`
- this file *isn't* mapped to `branch2`
- this file *is* mapped to `branch3`

Answer (score 3):

The doc you linked to has an example:

```
 -//a/b/file.txt //client/a/b/file.txt //home/_user_/root/a/b/file.txt
 //a/b/file.txt //client/b/file.txt /home/_user_/root/b/file.txt
```

which it explains thus:

```
 This can be interpreted as saying that the first line of the client
 view would have caused the file to appear in /home/user/root/a/b/file.txt,
 except that it was overridden by the second mapping in the view.
```

More generally, a leading hyphen was used to logically remove a line in a client view specification (I no longer use perforce day-to-day so I have forgotten the right terms).